# Python Pandas Dataframe calculating new row value based on previous row value within same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's a bit hard to explain, so I'll start off with what I'm trying to achieve using excel.

[image: Excel example]

Basically, the value of the "Active" column is based on values of the same row different column values (columns 'Act Count' and 'De Count'), as well as the value in the previous row of the "Active" column.

From the excel formula, if 'Act Count' < 4 and 'De Count' < 4, 'Active' = the previous row's 'Active' value.

I want to transition this to Python pandas dataframe.

Here is the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Act Count':[1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'De Count':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

You can assume the first row value of 'Active' = 0.

I know of .shift() function, however I feel like I can't use it because I can't shift a column that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but it will do the job.

```
import pandas as pd

act_count = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
de_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

active = [0]
for i in range(1:len(act_count)):
    if act_count[i] >= 4:
       active.append(100)
    elif de_count[i] >= 4 :
       active.append(0)
    else:
       active.append(active[i-1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Act Count': act_count, 'De Count' : de_count, 
              'Active' : active})
```

Comment: Thanks, this works however - sorry I didn't mention this - but my data is already in a dataframe of roughly 4000 rows. Unsure if this is the best way to process this. Furthermore, the '4' value that I've kept constant in this example, is actually another column in the dataframe that can change. I guess I can just use ```list(df['column_name']) for all the columns and creates lists to use your solution. Just doesn't seem ideal right now. Thank you! I'll wait to see if anyone else has a better solution using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
##Adding an empty column named Active to the existing dataframe
df['Active'] = np.nan

##putting the first value as 0
df['Active'].loc[0] = 0 

for index in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    if df['Act Count'].iloc[index]>=4:
        df['Active'].iloc[index]=100
    elif df['De Count'].iloc[index]>=4:
        df['Active'].iloc[index]=0
    else:
        df['Active'].iloc[index]=df['Active'].iloc[index-1]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Act Count    De Count    Active
0   1           0           0.0
1   2           0           0.0
2   3           0           0.0
3   4           0           100.0
4   0           0           100.0
5   0           0           100.0
6   0           0           100.0
7   0           0           100.0
8   0           1           100.0
9   0           2           100.0
10  0           3           100.0
11  0           4           0.0
12  0           5           0.0
13  0           6           0.0
```

Comment: This answer also works, however when applied to the full dataframe of >4000 rows, it took up to 90 seconds whereas the other method using lists took about 1 second.

Comment: have you tried putting this in a function and then using .apply() to the dataframe, that might speed it up.